# Making every page on a div rainbow

Tags: javascript, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create Javascript code that turns every div into a linear gradient.

Here's what I tried:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

elem.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, orange, green, blue, purple, pink)";
```

It's giving me this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'backgroundImage')`

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for myself! I just figured this out, and it works:

```
(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for(i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
        elem[i].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(red,orange,yellow,green,blue,purple,pink)"
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style *every* div, you'll need to iterate through all of the `div` elements:

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for( var x=0; x<elem.length; x++ ){
    elem[x].style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(45deg, red, yellow, orange, green, blue, purple, pink)";
}
```

```css
div{height:300px;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```